# How to Access a Database from an ASP.NET Application?

Tags: c#, database

i'm building a web application (asp.net & c#),
i want to connect it with db(which i'm building ) , and i looking for tutorial \ book about connecting with db and doing it safely (avoiding sql injections). 
my queries are very simple and not complex.

i read a little bit  about stored procedures,prepared statements,LiNQ
it's all really confusing me.

can someone point me where to read how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing a database in ASP.NET is no different than accessing a database in any .NET application simply because ASP.NET is a .NET application. And the way to access a relational database in .NET is to use [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021.aspx).

As long as you are using parametrized queries you are safe against SQL injection. Let's take an example with SQL Server:

```
string firstname = "John";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;"))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT lastname FROM mytable WHERE firstname = @firstname;";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstname);
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string lastName = reader.GetString(0);
            // do something with the value
        }
    }
}
```

Now compare with the following (**bad code**):

```
string firstname = "John";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;"))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT lastname FROM mytable WHERE firstname = '" + firstname + "';";
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string lastName = reader.GetString(0);
            // do something with the value
        }
    }
}
```

This second example is bad and vulnerable to SQL injection. So basically everytime you use the `+` operator when building your query string you are doing it wrong.

And once you get tired of writing all those SQL queries you may consider using an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). The one that's shipped with .NET is called [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty broad question. I would recommend you spend some time using Google to get a better understanding of ADO.NET as a starting point.

[Connecting to Databases in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178371.aspx)

[ASP.NET Data Access Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials)